# I can't change the fontsize on Listview items or column headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles, font-size

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstProductionOrders">
         <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Production Order:"/>
                        ...
```

I've set the fontsize on the grid, using textelement, I've set it on the listview, the columnheader, through styles, through styles using BasedOn. I even put in a brand new test window that had no other code in it but the default code and a listview created the same way above. Using all of the above, the font changes in design-time but not in run-time.

I've only got about 6 months of WPF/XAML experience, so I may be looking for the wrong thing. Is there some kind of global setting for fontsize or anything anyone can think of that would be causing this to be overridden.

For the record, I with the test window, there are no base classes.

----------EDIT----------

This was the source of the problem in App. xaml

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds a lot like you have an implicit style for GridViewColumn that overwrites changes you made locally.

At design time, that implicit style is not taken into account (could be for various reasons), but at runtime it is, and you get that strange behavior.

I would start by looking into App.xaml's Resources section, then move upwards until I reach the control I care about.

**Addition: implicit styles:**

```
<UserControl>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" /> <!-- stupid value, just to make it obvious it changed something =) -->
      </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

If you ever want to define an implicit style locally without overwriting another implicit style set higher up the chain, you can do this:

```
<UserControl>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" /> <!-- ridiculous value, just to make it obvious it changed something =) -->
      </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

It will inherit the implicit style in place and add changes for the local UserControl.

Comment: Nice! The TextBlock style is defined in App.xaml with a FontSize set. I never thought to look for TextBlock for the Listview header and items.  Awesome suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also define another implicit style for TextBlock in the local control. It will overwrite the global implicit style set in App.xaml

Comment: Damn, dude. Dropping all kinds of knowledge on me. I was just starting to look into how to override that. Thanks again. Who woulda thought a Baboon would know so much about XAML.

Comment: Glad it helps =) Implicit styles are just styles without x:Key, they will apply to any control of the TargetType that was set.

Comment: I tried your overwrite solution, but it didn't work. Tried it at the Window, Grid and ListView level Resources property. Do I have to provide any "path" information that points to App.xaml?

Comment: I provided an example for a TextBlock overwrite, if the implicit style that bugs you in your App.xaml targets ListViewItem, then you have to change the TargetType in your local implicit style accordingly.

Comment: See, that's the thing. The TextBlock implicit style was what was affecting the listview, not a listview or listviewitem style. When I removed that TextBlock implicit style from App.xaml, I could set the font on the column header or items in my local window. I assumed I'd have to overwrite the TextBlock style in the local window to do that. I added what I commented out above to my question.

Answer (score 5):

For me the following works for both header and items:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}"
          TextElement.FontSize="16">
    <!-- ... -->
```

No idea what could be wrong in your case though...

Answer (score 1):

if you want only set the header size, then try this solution
or use @H.B. solution

```
<ListView x:Name="lstProductionOrders" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader TextElement.FontSize="16">Production Order:/GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[image]

hope this helps

Comment: @Xcalibur37 Works like a charm! on my machine™ (i've updated my answer with a screenshot)

Comment: Sorry for knocking on your answer. I can't get this to work without directly putting a TextBlock inside the Content of the GridViewColumn Header. This isn't unheard of with GridView and DataGrid. It's something WPF needs to do better.